# Calculating a new Variable in R Based on Previous Variables

Tags: r, variables, merge

I have a data frame that has info for a bunch of companies over different years, something like

```
Company  Year   Ratio
Apple    2002   .2
Apple    2003   .3
Apple    2004   .2
3M       2001   .1
3M       2002   .3
```

What I need to do, is create a new variable/column that is either 1 if the ratio decreases for the given company from the previous year, and 0 otherwise.  For example,

```
Company  Year   Ratio  Change
Apple    2002   .2        0
Apple    2003   .3        0
Apple    2004   .2        1
3M       2001   .1        0
3M       2002   .3        0
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr::lag`. Assuming your data frame is named `df1` and that `Company`, `Year` is ordered as in your example:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(Change = ifelse(Ratio - lag(Ratio) < 0, 1, 0))
```

Result:

```
  Company  Year Ratio Change
1   Apple  2002   0.2     NA
2   Apple  2003   0.3      0
3   Apple  2004   0.2      1
4      3M  2001   0.1     NA
5      3M  2002   0.3      0
```

This generates `NA` in the case where there is no previous year, which I'd argue is the correct approach. You can always change `NA` to `0` using a second `mutate`:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(Change = ifelse(Ratio - lag(Ratio) < 0, 1, 0))
  mutate(Change = ifelse(is.na(Change), 0, Change))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$Change <- with(df1, ave(Ratio, Company, FUN = function(x) c(FALSE, diff(x) < 0)))
df1$Change 
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0
```